# Formview not showing

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created a formview using the Visual Studio resource editor but I can't get it to show.

The procedure to handle it's messages is this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD (wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTONCancel:
            EndDialog(hDlg,0);
            return TRUE;            
        }
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

When a button is pressed in the main window I call:

```
DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FORMVIEW), hwnd, (DLGPROC)DlgProc);
```

The main window freezes, but there is no dialog shown.

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the dialogs receive `WM_INITDIALOG`, not `WM_COMMAND`, but I'm not sure if this could freeze your main window.

Comment: Well DialogBox does not return control until the specified callback function terminates the modal dialog box by calling the `EndDialog()` function. The `WM_COMMAND` must capture the pushing of a button from the form view. But I can't figure out why there is no dialog showing.

Comment: Dialogs definitely receive `WM_COMMAND`, but I think you meant that they receive `WM_INITDIALOG` instead of `WM_CREATE`. This is true. `WM_CREATE` in the code should be replaced with `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Comment: Why are you casting the function pointer to `DLGPROC`? You shouldn't need a cast there, it's just hiding a potential compile-time error.

Comment: There is no error without the cast, also replaced the `WM_CREATE` with `WM_INITDIALOG` but there`s still no dialog window.

Comment: This seems to work on my PC. Could you create a minimal example which has the specified problem?

Comment: Hmm, there should be an error when you remove the cast. The dialog callback function ([`DialogProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) by convention) returns an `INT_PTR`, not a `BOOL`.

Comment: I've found my mistake. I feel really foolish :D The Style of the Form View was set to Child, not Popup and it drew the Form View underneath the other stuff in the main window, which is strange actually. Thanks for all of your help anyway guys. :)